# JavaScript Error In View - Loading Order

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an Index page that loads a script within a Razor @section Scripts

I am getting an error on load at

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Here is my script.  It is throwing the error at "$("input#autocomplete").autocomplete({"

```
@section scripts
{
<script type="text/javascript">
    var items;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("input#autocomplete").autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response) {
                $.ajax({....
```

My question is, does this have anything to do with the where the script section is placed in the view? (it is after the table with the autocomplete input).  The layout I am using does include the following in the head:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

Comment: Have you connected jquery ui with autocomplete plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you dont have the autocomplete plugin.

Download it from [this link](http://jqueryui.com/download/).